# How to hide tooltip?

Tags: html, css

I am using css to create tooltip, 4 tooltips are placed sequentially, 2nd tooltip appears on the popup content of 1st tooltip

The following code is placed in between jsp file in liferay, every jsp file has the tooltip code in it. If I open the 1st tooltip, other tooltips appear on the popup content of 1st tooltip,

I need to show the popup contents without any interruption. How do I do that?

My code is

```css
    .help-tip {
          position: absolute;
          top: 34px;
          right: 120px;
          text-align: center;
          background-color: #a3c2c2;
          border-radius: 50%;
          width: 14px;
          height: 10px;
          font-size: 10px;
          line-height: 16px;
          cursor: default;
        }
        .help-tip:before {
          content: '?';
          font-weight: normal;
          font-size: 10px;
          color: #fff;
        }
        .help-tip:hover p {
          display: block;
          transform-origin: 100% 0%;
          -webkit-animation: fadeIn 0.3s ease-in-out;
          animation: fadeIn 0.3s ease-in-out;
        }
        .help-tip p {
          /* The tooltip */
          display: none;
          text-align: center;
          /*background-color: #a3c2c2;*/
          padding: 5px;
          width: 170px;
          position: absolute;
          border-radius: 6px;
          box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
          right: -100px;
          /*color: #000000;*/
          font-size: 14px;
          line-height: 1.4;
          color: #000000;
          background: #FBF5E6;
          background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #FBF5E6, #FFFFFF);
          background: linear-gradient(top, #FBF5E6, #FFFFFF);
          border: 1px solid #CFB57C;
        }
        .help-tip p:before {
          /* The pointer of the tooltip */
          position: absolute;
          content: '';
          width: 0;
          height: 0;
          border: 6px solid transparent;
          border-bottom-color: #66ccff;
          right: 100px;
          top: -12px;
        }
        .help-tip p:after {
          /* Prevents the tooltip from being hidden */
          width: 100%;
          height: 40px;
          content: '';
          position: absolute;
          top: -40px;
          left: 0;
        }
        /* CSS animation */
        @-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
          0% {
            opacity: 0;
            transform: scale(0.6);
          }
          100% {
            opacity: 100%;
            transform: scale(1);
          }
        }
        @keyframes fadeIn {
          0% {
            opacity: 0;
          }
          100% {
            opacity: 100%;
          }
        }
```

```html
    <div class="help-tip">
      <p>This is the inline edit help tip!</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: Due to using the exact same code for each tooltip, every tooltip will have the CSS property, 'position: absolute;' and that could be causing the problem. Try changing all the `position`s to `relative`

Comment: thank you josh.... its working

Comment: Please accept my answer so if anyone else trips over the same problem, they can easily see the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Due to using the exact same code for each tooltip, every tooltip will have the CSS property, `position: absolute;` and that could be causing the problem. Try changing all the `position`s to `relative`.